# Is it possible to locate android device by guid?

Tags: android, networking, guid, skype, locate

Is it possible to locate android device by  guid? I mean the city where the device currently located or the coordinates ( longitude latitude )

Comment: by using guid given by manufacturer? if such thing exists, how can you trust it for the device can "fly" from one country to another country? also, what is the use of GPS ?

Comment: well skype system command shows that someone uses my skype id from android device and it shows its guid . I wonder if there is any way to get its current location

Answer (score 0):

No.

At most you could use it as a key to tie together different pieces of information you learn about the device by other methods, such as having code on the device utilize the location APIs and report the results.